# Rolling bullet points in beamer

Tags: beamer, lists, overlays

Often when I use beamer for slides I use an `itemize` environment with `\pause` to show off one bullet point at a time. Also, often all the points I want to show on a single slide does not fit and I need to start a new slide with a couple of more points.

What I would like is instead an `itemize`-like environment that would give me (when the points do not fit on a single slide) rolling bullet points, something similar to what the following code does:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \only<-5>{\item one}
            \only<2-6>{\item two}
            \only<3-7>{\item three}
            \only<4-8>{\item four}
            \only<5-9>{\item five}
            \only<6-10>{\item six}
            \only<7-11>{\item seven}
            \only<8-12>{\item eight}
            \only<9->{\item nine}
            \only<10->{\item ten}
            \only<11->{\item eleven}
            \only<12->{\item twelve}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However I don't want to keep track of how many slides I'm using.

Is there such an environment out there somewhere?

Also, some sort of animated rolling would be excellent, but that might be to ask for to much.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: See [Beamer Animations: How to simulate terminal input and output](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37869/beamer-animations-how-to-simulate-terminal-input-and-output)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is built into beamer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}[<only@+-+(4)>]
        \item one
        \item two
        \item three
        \item four
        \item five
        \item six
        \item seven
        \item eight
        \item nine
        \item ten
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The overlay specification `+-+(4)` means the same thing as `(n+1)-(n+5)`, where `n` is the current slide count.  The `only@` action wraps the item in an `\only<...>`.  Putting the specification as an argument to the `itemize` environment makes it the default for each item.

If you want to specify item text in a `\foreach` loop you can explicitly call `\only` before each item:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \foreach \x in {a,b,...,z} {%
            \only<+-+(4)>{\item \x}
        }
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

See sections 9.6.3 (Action Specifications) and 9.6.4 (Incremental Specifications) of the beamer (v3.22) manual.  Also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6407/1402) of mine.

Comment: Thanks for this tip I didn' know, it does not work with a `\foreach` loop, but `Tom`'s solution does : \begin{frame}[t]
    \begin{itemize}
    \foreach \x in {a,...,z} {%
        \myitem{\x \theiii}
    }
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
will work, but \begin{itemize}[<only@+-+(4)>]
       \foreach \x in {a,...,z} {%
        \item \x
    } 
    \end{itemize} will not.

Comment: @Tarass: see edit.

Comment: This should be marked as the "correct" answer!

Comment: That's great and I'll sure use it. However, in the best of worlds I don't want to keep track of how many of my bullet points actually fit on a slide. Let's say that the first four bullet points fit fine on a single slide but the fifth takes more space so then I want only bullet points 3, 4, and 5 to show on the second slide. And so on. Is there an *easy* way of accomplishing this?

Comment: @feffemannen: That's a good question.  So you would like to have, for each step, the maximum number of bullet points through that step that will fit on the slide, to appear?  That seems possible but I'm not skilled enough to do it.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a version, with a rather weird problem and therefore a limitation. It defines a new counter `iii` and a new `\myitem` command. If you use such `itemize` environments on more than one slide, then the counter has to be reset. Otherwise, if for example you had 10 points on the first slide, it would start at slide 11 on the next slide. So I used *etoolbox*'s `\AtBeginEnvironment` to reset the `iii` counter. This however means that you can only use one such `itemize` list per `frame` as otherwise you'll scroll through both of them at the same time. I tried to improve this by reseting the `iii` counter at the begin of each `frame`. But if I don't have the line `\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\setcounter{iii}{0}}` I get a large pile of errors (*"perhaps a missing item"*), so for the moment this is limited to one scrolling `itemize` per `frame`. Also, as there's no look ahead mechanism, it won't stop when the last 5 items are displayed, but only when the last one is present.

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{iii}

\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\setcounter{iii}{0}}

\newcommand{\myitem}[2][$\bullet$]
{ \stepcounter{iii}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\endslide}{\theiii+4}
    \only<\theiii-\endslide>{\item[#1] #2}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
    \begin{itemize}
        \myitem{a \theiii}
        \myitem{b \theiii}
        \myitem{c \theiii}
        \myitem{d \theiii}
        \myitem{e \theiii}
        \myitem{f \theiii}
        \myitem{g \theiii}
        \myitem{h \theiii}
        \myitem{i \theiii}
        \myitem{j \theiii}
        \myitem{k \theiii}
        \myitem{l \theiii}
        \myitem{m \theiii}
        \myitem{n \theiii}
        \myitem{o \theiii}
        \myitem{p \theiii}
        \myitem{q \theiii}
        \myitem{r \theiii}
        \myitem{s \theiii}
        \myitem{t \theiii}
        \myitem{u \theiii}
        \myitem{v \theiii}
        \myitem{w \theiii}
        \myitem{x \theiii}
        \myitem{y \theiii}
        \myitem{z \theiii}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Great, that looks like it should work! I'll try that for the next slides I produce.

Answer (score 1):

For reference as an extension to @Matthew Leingang's excellent answer.
here is how you hardcode the beginning and end to avoid  even having the list display less than 4 items.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \only<-1>{\item 1}
        \only<-2>{\item 2}
        \only<-3>{\item 3}
        \only<+-+(3)>{\item 5}
        \only<+-+(3)>{\item 6}
        \only<+-+(3)>{\item 7}
        \only<+-+(3)>{\item 8}
        \only<+-+(3)>{\item 9}
        \only<+-+(3)>{\item 10}
        \only<+-+(3)>{\item 11}
        \only<+-+(3)>{\item 12}
        \only<+-+(3)>{\item 13}
        \only<+->{\item 14}
        \only<+->{\item 15}
        \only<+->{\item 16}
        \only<+->{\item 17}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```