# How to advance HALF of a beamer slide

Tags: beamer

I need to give beamer presentations with a lot of bullet points.  The audience often ask for extra time so they can copy them, and periodically I need to go back to the previous slide to refer to a statement near the end.

Q:  Is there a way to advanced just HALF a slide, like this:

slide N:

(top half of slide N)

(bottom half of slide N)

NEXT SLIDE:

(bottom half of slide N)

(top half of slide N+1)

NEXT SLIDE:

(top half of slide N+1)

(bottom half of slide N+1)

Of course I want to do this without creating a new slide (or frame).

Note: I'm aware of the issues of putting too much content on one slide, going too far etc.  For the purpose of this question let's stick to beamer.  THANKS :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! You could just store the halves of the slides in macros, say, `\topN`, `\botN`, `\topM`, `\botM` and could then use `\begin{frame}\frametitle{...} \topN \botN \end{frame} \begin{frame}\frametitle{...} \botN \topM \end{frame} \begin{frame}\frametitle{...} \topM \botM \end{frame}` etc.

Comment: Maybe this is close to what you want to achieve: `\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
 \item<1-> visible on first slide
 \item<3-> visible on third slide
\end{itemize}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item<1-> visible on first slide
 \item<2-> visible on second slide
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}`

Comment: @marmot:  This sounds like a good idea --- could you provide a MWE?

Comment: Two more suggestions: by using https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100102/36296 you could "scroll" through your bullet points so the last few items will always be visible. Or you could change the paper format for one slide and have all items on the same page. If you don't use presentation mode but full screen mode of your pdf viewer you should be able to scroll through the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, per request. Note that this is a very simple example, and you will be even better off if you just use `<1-2>` and the like for the items. However, for more complex examples this may pay off. In any case, I will be happy to remove this if it is not useful.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikzducks,tikzlings}
\newcommand{\topA}{\begin{itemize}
\item this is a duck: \tikz[baseline=2em]{\duck}
\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\botA}{\begin{itemize}
\item this is a mouse: \tikz[baseline=2em]{\mouse}
\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\topB}{\begin{itemize}
\item this is a koala: \tikz[baseline=2em]{\koala}
\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\botB}{\begin{itemize}
\item this is a marmot: \tikz[baseline=2em]{\marmot}
\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Ti\emph{k}Zlings: duck and mouse}

\topA

\botA

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Ti\emph{k}Zlings: mouse and koala}
\botA

\topB
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Ti\emph{k}Zlings: koala and marmot}

\topB

\botB

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This, which is conceptually very similar tp [leandriis' suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478763/how-to-advance-half-of-a-beamer-slide?noredirect=1#comment1209272_478763) yields almost the same result (except for no top alignment, which I fail to understand, but this is definitely my fault).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikzducks,tikzlings}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Ti\emph{k}Zlings: \only<1>{duck}\only<2>{mouse}\only<3>{koala} and 
\only<1>{mouse}\only<2>{koala}\only<3>{marmot}}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1> this is a duck: \tikz[baseline=2em]{\duck}
\item<1-2> this is a mouse: \tikz[baseline=2em]{\mouse}
\item<2-3> this is a koala: \tikz[baseline=2em]{\koala}
\item<3> this is a marmot: \tikz[baseline=2em]{\marmot}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

So I guess we will have to wait until @samcarter writes a real answer.